# SSRS 2008 R2 - 'Complex' Grouping

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have to create a report that requires grouping that doesn't seem to be straight forward in SSRS.

```
COL_ID   |    COL_FIELD1|  COL_FIELD2   | COL_FIELD 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |      ABC     |       |     CBA        
    1    |      DEF     |   5   |     LOT        
         |      GHI     |       |     JKH        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2    |      UIO     |   7   |     JHG       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    6    |      PLK     |   6   |     HHJ        
         |      GTR     |       |           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Column COL_ID is the ID and identifies all 'cases'. If multiples cases under one ID,
have the same values in a column the cells should be vertically merged and the value
should be displayed only once.

I hope the example table illustrates how it should look like.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is possible in SSRS.

I was trying this approach, but it doesn't work on your example.. but it can maybe give you more ideas:

- Create 4 groups (one for each of the columns): G1, G2, G3, G4
- On the 2nd group, the expression on the textbox should be `IIF(RowNumber("G1") = 1, Fields!Field1.Value,"")`
- On the 3rd group, the expression on the textbox should be `IIF(RowNumber("G1") = 1 AND RowNumber("G2") = 1, Fields!Field1.Value,"")` (by doing this we only show the first occurrence on the group)
- On the 4th group add the G3 condition..

To fix the Top and Bottom borders on each cell that now has an empty text you need to set an expression on the Top and Bottom properties, depending on the group cells you're selecting:

- Top: `IIF(RowNumber("G1") = 1 AND RowNumber("G2") = 1, "Default", "None")`
- Bottom: `IIF(RowNumber("G1") = CountRows("G1") AND RowNumber("G2") = CountRows("G2"), "Default", "None")`